# Copy de un server(windows) a otro server(windows)

Tags: windows, batch

No encuentro la sintaxis correcta para poder hacer un *copy*, ya hice ping y si hay respuesta entre los servidores.

Se va a cargar un archivo desde `180.176.114.15` que esta en *C* y se llama `installAgent.log` y se va a llevar a otro servidor desde el cual se ejecuta el script.

```
Copy "180.176.114.15:\C:\installAgent.log" "D:\BDS\REPORTE_USO_TOKEN_30042018.txt"
```

Comment: En primer lugar asegúrate de tener una carpeta compartida, supongamos que compartieras el disco `C` completo (mala práctica) y el recurso compartido lo llamaras "midisco", deberías hacer entonces algo así: `copy "\\180.176.114.15\midisco\installAgent.log" "D:\BDS\REPORTE_USO_TOKEN_30042018.txt"`

Answer (score 0):

Los dos puntos que tendrás que tener el cuenta son los privilegios de quien ejecute el comando, que deberá tener en permisos en ambos servidores, de lectura al menos sobre el origen y de escritura en destino.
Segundo, deberás tener los puertos para compartir ficheros abiertos, en principio el 445. el ping no te garantiza que el puerto este abierto.
La sintaxis para tu comando sin tener que compartir, que no es necesario si tienes los privilegios necesarios seria:

```
Copy "\\180.176.114.15\C$\installAgent.log" "D:\BDS\REPORTE_USO_TOKEN_30042018.txt"
```

Para copias de ficheros te recomendaría el uso de robocopy dado que es mas robusto, aunque para tu caso tiene el inconveniente de que no tiene la capacidad de renombrar.